# Tomar datos de una función jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, select2

Tengo el siguiente script para buscar un producto en un select2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#productSelect").select2({
    placeholder: 'Seleccione un Producto',
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
      url: 'PrdSearch.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 50,
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: data
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });

});
```

y el archivo PrdSearch.php que hace la busqueda

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
if (empty($_GET['q'])) exit ;
$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $q = stripslashes($q);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " .$database_table_prefix."products" . " WHERE prd_name like '%$q%' or prd_code like '%$q%' ORDER BY prd_name LIMIT 20";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
$result = [];
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $result [] = ['id'=>$row['prd_id'], 'text'=>$row['prd_name']];
}
echo json_encode($result);?>
```

Funciona bien y trae el prd_id y prd_name de un solo producto en los valores de  id y de text respectivamente, el nombre se ubica como valor en el `<select>` correctamente.

He intentado traer mas datos del producto como codigo y precio entre otros agregando las claves y los valores en el array $result, no me da ningún error pero no se como recuperar esos datos adicionales del array, se que el valor de "text" se queda en el `<select>` pero los otros campos como los recupero?

Lo otro es, si ya tengo los campos como asigno los valores a los input del formulario?

Gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Los datos de `select2` de guardan en `e.params.data`, entonces el script queda asi:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

      $('#productSelect').on("select2:select", function (e) {
        $("#inv_code").val(e.params.data.code);
        $("#inv_price").val(e.params.data.price);
       });


      $("#productSelect").select2({
        placeholder: 'Seleccione un Producto',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
          url: 'PrdSearch.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          delay: 50,
          processResults: function (data) {
            return {
              results: data
            };
          },
          cache: true
        }
      });

    });
```

Gracias a todos por su aporte.